# Magento M2ePro Ebay / Wrong counting inactive items

Tags: magento-1.9, m2e-pro

I have an issue with m2epro. There's a wrong counting for inactive items.
I don't have this item in listing! Listing counting 20 items, but if I see in "detailed listing" there are 19. I'm not able to see the active items.
Where I'm wrong?

[This is the link to screenshot](http://www.shoppylandia.it/listing.jpg)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why this happens, but to work around it. From the listings page, click on manage from the action dropdown list. This will show you the inactive listings. I hope this helps